# Ordering queryset by filtered child objects

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have the following (simplified) data model, see visual representation below the post:

- Articles, which have Attributes
- Attributes refer by PK to a Type, which have a field code
- Attributes have a field value
- The value refers to the field uuid in another model called Record, which also has a field sorting_code

I now want to return a list of articles in a certain ordering, using pagination. I am using a default ViewSet for it. The pagination forces me to do the ordering in database, instead of later in Python. However, I cannot seem to find the correct `ordering` clause that orders these articles. What I need to do is:

- Fetch the Attribute with a specific type
- Look up the values in those Attributes in the Record table
- Order the articles based by sorting_code

The following SQL query does the job (for all articles):

```
SELECT art.order_id, art.uuid, att.value, mdr.code, mdr.name, mdr.sorting_code
FROM ow_order_article art
INNER JOIN ow_order_attribute att ON att.article_id = art.uuid
INNER JOIN ow_masterdata_type mdt ON att.masterdata_type_id = mdt.uuid
INNER JOIN ow_masterdata_record mdr ON att.value = mdr.uuid
WHERE mdt.code = 'article_structure'
ORDER BY mdr.sorting_code, mdr.code
```

What would be the correct way to get this ordering in a queryset in Django?

[image: Data model simplified]

Comment: Please share your django models